# Product / subscription / membership for places on a physical veg box scheme?

Tags: commerce

My client can provide max 30 veg boxes at any one time, delivered physically. A purchase buys a weekly delivery for 6 weeks (ie 6 veg boxes). When the 6 week period is over, deliveries stop. So there are max 30 places on the veg box scheme. After each customer's 6 week membership has lapsed, the stock level needs to be incremented by 1, indicating that there is now a free place on the scheme.

So I need a way of setting a lapse period on a product (6 weeks), along with a total-stock-at-any-one-time (30 places) setting, which needs to be aware of orders currently in date.

Recurring billing is not required, as customers will have to re-order if they want another 6 weeks membership on the scheme.

I am developing a new site in Commerce 2. Is this use case covered and where? I have hunted in commerce_stock and commerce_subscription and docs and videos, but I can't find anything.

Also client needs to print out, every week, names and delivery locations of each person in credit that week. I'm hoping that would be covered by views.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this through views and configuration, such a project requires heavy amounts of custom code.

[Eldum Rett](https://www.drupal.org/case-study/food-delivery-service-built-on-decoupled-drupal-commerce-with-react-native-app) is a Commerce 2.x site built for the same use case. You could contact 1xInternet for consulting, since they built it.

Under the hood it's [Commerce Recurring](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring), [Commerce Recurring Shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring_shipping) plus custom code.